# How can I access the controller of a nested component from its parent?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have three Angular 1.5 components: `ReportFilter` and `ClientSelect`, `ZoneSelect`.

ReportFilter has the two components inside of it

```
<!-- Report Filter -->
<div>
    <client-select client="$ctrl.selections.client"></client-select>
    <zone-select zone="$ctrl.selections.zone"></zone-select>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.search()">Get Report</button>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.clear()">Clear</button>
</div>
```

`client` and `zone` are two-way data bound, so that when the user selects a client or a zone, the respective properties are updated in my `ReportFilter`'s selections.

**My Question:**

How can I call a `reset()` method on the controller of my `ClientSelect` or `ZoneSelect` components from inside of the `ReportFilter`'s controller?

React has a `ref` tag that lets you gain access to the controller to call methods on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the preferred approach to take is in your child directive you can add a scope attribute called api:

```
app.directive('childDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      api: "=?"
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      return {
        scope.someFN = function() {
           // do stuff.
        };

        scope.api = {
         someFN: scope.someFN
        };
      };
    };
  };
});
```

Then when you call the directive you simply pass a scope attribute:

```
<div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
  <child-directive api="foo"></child-directive>
</div>
```

And you can now call functions from the parent controller with

```
$scope.foo.someFN()
```

Comment: I've seen several other components (such as UI-Grid) use this approach as well.

Comment: I have noticed some odd behaviors with some libraries that do this... for example angular-nvd3 usually requires you to provide an `on-ready` function to actually populate the scope variable.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the intended behavior however because angular-nvd3 also allows you to define api, but it doesn't seem to actually populate the variable unless you do so inside the on-ready function.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way (unlike React, as you mention :)

A possible solution is to let the children require their parent, and register themselves to it:

```
    // child directive
    .directive('clientSelect', function() { // `.component` is similar...
        return {
            ...
            controller: ClientSelect,
            require: ['clientSelect', 'reportFilter'],
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrls) {
                ctrls[1].setClientSelect(ctrls[0]);
                // do not forget to deregister, just in case
                scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                    ctrls[1].setClientSelect(null);
                });
            }
        };
    })

    // parent directive
    .directive('reportFilter', function() {
        function ReportFilter() {
            ...
        }

        ReportFilter.prototype.setClientSelect = function(clientSelect) {
            this.clientSelect = clientSelect;
        };

        ReportFilter.prototype.somethingElse = function() {
            // reset the clientSelect:
            this.clientSelect.reset();
        };

        return {
            ...
            controller: ReportFilter,
            ...
        };
    })
```

If you do *not* want the coupling between the children and the parent components, then you can redesign the children so that all their data, and I mean all, the entire thing, come from their parent. In this case, to reset the `clientSelect`, the parent controller just needs to clear the data it shares with it, i.e. do:

```
// in the parent controller
this.selections.client = {}; // or null or...
```

Comment: I like this approach except for the fact that the directive now has a dependency on a specific controller.

Comment: This coupling is indeed bad, if the directives are meant to be independent components. However it is not, if they are meant to work together from a usability perspective. E.g. nodes in a tree are always part of a... tree. Requiring their parent "tree" component does not result in any more coupling.

Comment: This idea _could_ work, but I plan to use the `clientSelect` and `reportFiler` components in other places besides the `ReportFilter`.

Comment: @sflogen bare in mind this approach is the best approach to take if the parentController and the childController have interlacing dependencies.  In a project I am working on we use this very approach in a parent/child relationship were the child needs variables and shared functions from the parent and the parent needs access to the child's API.